# How to fix intermittent 503 Service Unavailable after idling/redeployments on AWS HTTP API Gateway & Fargate/ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate

We've got a quite simple setup which causes us major headaches:

1. **HTTP API Gateway** with a S3 Integration for our static HTML/JS and a `ANY /api/{proxy+}` **route to a Fargate Service/Tasks** accessible via **Cloud Map**
2. **ECS Cluster** with a *"API service"* using **Fargate** and a Container Task exposing Port 8080 via `awsvpc`. No autoscaling. Min healthy: 100%, Max: 200%.
3. Service discovery using  `SRV` DNS record with `TTL 60`
4. The **ECS service/tasks is completely bored/idling** and always happy to accept requests while logging them.

#### Problem:

We receive *intermittent* `HTTP 503 Service Unavailable` for some of our requests. A new deployment (with task redeployment) increases the rate, but even after 10-15 minutes they still occur intermittently.

In Cloud Watch we see the failing 503 Requests

```
2020-06-05T14:19:01.810+02:00 xx.117.163.xx - - [05/Jun/2020:12:19:01 +0000] "GET ANY /api/{proxy+} HTTP/1.1" 503 33 Np24bwmwsiasJDQ=
```

but it seems like they do not reach a living backend instance.

We enabled VPC Flow Logs and it seems that **HTTP API Gateway wants to route some requests to stopped tasks even after they've gone long for good** (far exceeding 60s).

More puzzling: If we keep the system busy, the rate drops to nearly zero. Otherwise after a longer period of idling the intermittent errors seem to reoccur.

#### Questions

1. How can we fix this issue?
2. Are there options to further pinpoint the root issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issues and solved it by configuring my ALB being **internal**, instead of **internet-facing**(regarding the **scheme**). Hope it may help someone with the same issue.

**Context:** The environment is API Gateway + ALB(ECS)

**Update**
The first ALB I configured was to manage my backend services. Recently I also did another ALB(to deal with my front-end instances), in this case, I exposed a public IP(instead of just a private one). This could be achieved by changing the scheme to **internet-facing**, at first I thought this would bring the same problem as I had before, then I figured that it was something pretty simple. I just needed to add a policy to allow traffic from the internet to the ALB I created.

Answer (score 1):

Though we were never able to really pinpoint down the issue we've come to the conclusion that this was a combination of

- temporary internal AWS issues causing long delays for HTTP API Gateway to adopt Route 53 zone updates (used for service discovery) and
- the absence of an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB)

Replacing the API Gateway with Cloudfront functionality and introducing an AWS Application Load Balancer switched the method for service discovery: Instead of a Route 53 zone the ELB manages the available ECS/Fargate tasks on their own. This salvaged this issue for us besides a few other minor ones.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was, in addition to configuring my ALB's scheme as **internal** as [xaalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9090837/xaalves) did, also putting the ALB in an **Isolated** or a **Private** subnet. Previously I had my ALB in **Public** subnets. [bentolor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237653/bentolor)'s experience got me thinking that some sort of DNS resolution was going haywire, and sure enough that appeared to be the case. Now 100% of my HTTP calls complete successfully.

Comment: Thanks, [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5534685/brian-schalme): This sound promising. It seems that the public infrastructure shares different update timing properties.